# AngularJs dynamic Event Handling for the whole page level

Tags: angularjs

I want to create following event(s) using angularjs.

- mousemove
- keydown
- DOMMouseScroll
- mousewheel
- mousedown
- touchstart
- touchmove
- scroll

Now what I am trying is as following...,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appname">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>    
</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('appname', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  alert("Hello");
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {

      scope.appname.$on('mousemove', function() {
        alert("mousemove");
      });

      scope.appname.$on('keydown', function() {
        alert("keydown");
      });

      scope.appname.$on('DOMMouseScroll', function() {
        alert("DOMMouseScroll");
      });    

    });
  }
});
</script>

</html>
```

But I cannot get it working. Let me get your suggestions.

Comment: check out this plunkr this should give you an idea http://plnkr.co/edit/5U8mr8gBTQJajLzb3wSj?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Since each `$scope` inherits from the `$rootScope` and you are not using an isolated scope here, you can use `$rootScope.$on` to subscribe to the events for your whole application.

A great introduction can [be found here](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/).

Answer (score 0):

After,I learned from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627061/900284), I got it working in following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>

var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.run(['$document', function($document) {
    var bodyElement = angular.element($document);
    bodyElement.bind('click', function (e) {
        console.log('click');
    });
    bodyElement.bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        console.log('mousemove');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        console.log('keydown');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        console.log('DOMMouseScroll');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        console.log('mousewheel');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        console.log('mousedown');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('touchstart', function (e) {
        console.log('touchstart');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('touchmove', function (e) {
        console.log('touchmove');
    }); 
    bodyElement.bind('scroll', function (e) {
        console.log('scroll');
    }); 
}]);

</script>

</html>
```

Demo [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PlZTdxftwmqFt6rIeGc)